# How to timer is running while process.waiforexit()?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, process, timer

My form contain two controls: button1 and timer1

```
timer1.Interval=1000; timer1.Enable=true;
```

While click button1, application on windows will start. Ex:notepad will show.
But timer1 is not running while notepad is showing.
How to timer1 so running ??.

My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process pro = new Process();
    pro.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad";
    pro.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
    pro.Start();
    pro.WaitForExit();
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dtime = DateTime.Now;
    string date_time = dtime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    textBox2.Text = date_time;
}
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that the timer is not running? Is it because the textbox does not update? That doesn't mean the timer is not running.

Comment: remove the pro.WaitForExit() and it will continue to update the textbox

Comment: @John Saunders, I tried don't use textbox and replace which text file like log.txt, every 1 seconds I will write date_time to file. but don't seen result.

Comment: @ terrybozzio, if remove the pro.WaiForExit, I was don't create this topic.

Answer (score 5):

From [`Process.WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Instructs the Process component to **wait indefinitely** for the associated process to exit.

Your timer is trying to invoke `timer1_Tick`, but your UI Thread is currently stuck waiting for the process to exit, which it wont.

You have two choices to work around this:

1. Simply remove the call to `WaitForExit` if you dont really need to wait
2. If you do need to be notified when the process exits, set `Process.EnableRaisingEvents` to `true` and register to the [`Process.Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx) event

Answer (score 2):

The WaitForExit() is "blocking" your interface from refreshing,the call just waits there for the process to exit. As an alternative if you need to do something when the process as exited do this:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process pro = new Process();
            pro.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad";
            pro.StartInfo.Arguments = "";

            //if you need to do something when the process  exits do this:
            pro.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            pro.Exited += new EventHandler(pro_Exited);
            pro.Start();
            //pro.WaitForExit();
        }

        void pro_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do what you need here...
        }
```

Instead you could start the process with a BackGroundWorker.

Answer (score 1):

`pro.WaitForExit();` makes UI thread to freeze so it can't update.

To stop user from actions, you can disable some controls, while process is running. You can subscribe to `process.Exited` event and enable your controls, when user closes the process.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process pro = new Process();
    pro.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad";
    pro.StartInfo.Arguments = "";
    pro.Start();
    button1.Enabled = false;
    pro.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    pro.Exited += pro_Exited;
}

void pro_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     button1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { button1.Enabled = true; });
}
```

**Update**

As another answer suggested you should set `EnableRaisingEvents` property to `true`.
Also `pro_Exited` method will run in a different thread, so you need to use `Control.Invoke` method to change UI.

**Update 2**
If can't delete `pro.WaitForExit();` you can use another timer, because `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is running in UI thread and is blocked with it.

```
private System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(Callback);

public Form()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer.Change(0, 1000);
}

private void Callback(object state)
{
    DateTime dtime = DateTime.Now;
    string date_time = dtime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    button1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { textBox1.Text = date_time; });
}
```

It will not update the `textBox`, when `process` is opened, but the timer will run and can do some work.

**Update 3**
In case of multiple processes you can count them and check number of active processes in `pro_Exited` method.

```
private volatile int activeProcessCount = 0;
private void pro_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    activeProcessCount--;
    if (activeProcessCount == 0)
    {
        button1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { button1.Enabled = true; });
    }
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code
    activeProcessCount = 2;
    pro1.Start();
    pro2.Start();
}
```

Comment: In this case contain 1 process. I can use your code.    But if solution contain multi process. EX:process1,porcess2      
I need process1.WaitForExit() to run process2... process3..

Comment: yeah!! it is working fine.<br/> Thank you very much. <br/> I use System.Threading.Time not use System.Windows.Forms.Timer.